# next 3 from this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <tr>
   <td><div class="click">a</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="click">b</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="click">c</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="click">d</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="click">e</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="click">f</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="click">g</div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td><div class="click">h</div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td><div class="click">i</div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td><div class="click">j</div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td><div class="click">k</div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td><div class="click">l</div></td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td><div class="click">m</div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td><div class="click">n</div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td><div class="click">o</div></td>
 </tr>  
</table> 

$('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('red');
})
```

LIVE: http://jsbin.com/ibofis/1/edit

this working ok, but i would like add for this addClass for 3 next elements.

For example if i click on **c** then class .red should add for: **c**, **d**, **e** and **f**.

How can i make it?

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').andSelf().nextAll(':lt(3)').find('div').addClass('class');

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this).closest('tr');
   $this.nextUntil().filter(':lt(3)').add($this).find('div').addClass('red');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ibofis/2/edit

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the bottom, after the `$(this).addClass('red');` line:

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll(':lt(3)').find('div').addClass('red');
```

Comment: @pmandell Yeah, this would be added after the `$(this).addClass('red');` line in OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('red');
  var counter = 0, clickedEl = this;
  $('.click').each(function(ind, el){
    if(counter-- > 0){
      $(el).addClass('red');
    }
    if(el == clickedEl){
      counter = 3;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.nextAll()` and filter the objects using `.slice()`
So to toggle the .red class for the current and next 3 items:

**This adds the .red class to the `TR`.**

```
$(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('red').nextAll().slice(0,3).toggleClass('red');
```

[jsBIN](http://jsbin.com/ibofis/26/edit)

**This adds the .red class to the `DIV`**

```
$(this).toggleClass('red').closest("tr").nextAll().slice(0,3).each(function() {
    $(this).find(".click").toggleClass("red");
  });
});
```

[jsBIN](http://jsbin.com/ibofis/41/edit)

Where `slice(0 = index, 3 = length)`, I.E. start from the 1st object and limit to 3 objects.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.click').click(function(){

var thisIndex = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
  for(i=1; i<4; i++){
$("table").find('tr:eq('+(thisIndex+i)+')').addClass('red');
  $(this).addClass('red');
  }
});
```

Excuse the formatting!

Answer (score 2):

```
$e =  $('.click');

$e.click(function(){
   $i = $e.index($(this));
   $e.slice($i,$i+4).toggleClass('red');
});
```

Get the **index** of clicked element and use **.slice** to get the correct subset.

Answer (score 2):

add id's to the divs example:
a div has id 1, B div has id 2 and so on

then you can update ur js as following

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('red');
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
     var ids = '#' + id;  
   $(ids).addClass('red');
    id++;
     }
});
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

try this. if you want to toggle change `addClass` to `toggleClass`

```
$('.click').click(function(e){
  var clicks=$('.click');
  for(var i=0;i<clicks.length;i++)
      {
        if ($(this).text()==$(clicks[i]).text())
          {
             for(j=i;j<i+4;j++)
             {
               if ($(clicks[j])!=undefined) {
               $(clicks[j]).addClass("red");}
             }
          }
      }

});
```

Comment: clumsy - see the other solutions for more elegant jQuery